# Windows 2003 SBS - Default Share Size

Tags: windows-server-2003, network-share, windows-sbs-2003, directory

I setup a server for myself about 6 months ago but have only recently noticed that the network shares all have a default maximum size of 1GB.

How do I adjust this upwards, as I have other servers that do not have this restriction in place?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default SBS has 1GB quote on shares. To adjust or remove the quota, follow the steps in [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-6117811.html).